# Hadoop 1.0.4 Distributed Cache Error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am building a log analysis program in MapReduce. For which I am using MaxMind GeoIP data. Now I want to put the GeoIP data into Distributed Cache. I am developing my application in eclipse. Here is what I am doing

```
Job job = new Job();        
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(args[3]), job.getConfiguration());
```

Where args[3] will have the path.

Here I am using it

```
protected void setup(Context context) {
    try {
        //String dbfile = "GeoIP//GeoIPCountry.dat";

        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf =  context.getConfiguration();

        Path[] dbfile = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf); 

        // GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE - load database into memory, faster
        // performance but uses more memory, Increase the JVM heap Size
        cl = new LookupService(dbfile.toString(), LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error opening GeoIP data file.");
        System.err.println(e);
        System.exit(2);
    }
}
```

But while running I am getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method addCacheFile(URI, Configuration) in the type DistributedCache is not applicable for the arguments (URI, Configuration)
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Please help

Comment: Can you show your imports in the part when you're adding your file to the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its picking up the wrong classes:

```
The method addCacheFile(URI, Configuration) in the type DistributedCache is not applicable for the arguments (URI, Configuration)
```

check you imports for `URI` and `Configuration` classes.

As per the [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html#addCacheFile%28java.net.URI,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29), they should be `java.net.URI` and `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration`

I think you might have messed up with [javax.security.auth.login.Configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.html) class from jdk. Thats not supposed to be used here.